# how to set column count for each row dynamically in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have gridView builder which is displaying 2 items in a row. like below image
[image]

I want to display like this image
[image]

\n
Please help me to achieve this in flutter

```
                            GridView.builder(
                              gridDelegate:
                                  SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                                      maxCrossAxisExtent: 200,
                                      childAspectRatio: 2.5 / 3,
                                      crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                                      mainAxisSpacing: 10),
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              primary: false,
                              itemCount: nListLevels.modules.length,
                              itemBuilder: (context, j) {
        
                          // displaying contents here
                         }
                   ));
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can return "column" and inside the "column", you can add "Row" widget to suit your UI

Answer (score 0):

for different size of grid items, you need [flutter_staggered_grid_view](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view):

```
StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
  crossAxisCount: 4,
  itemCount: 8,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => new Container(
      color: Colors.green,
      child: new Center(
        child: new CircleAvatar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          child: new Text('$index'),
        ),
      )),
  staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) =>
      new StaggeredTile.count(2, index.isEven ? 2 : 1),
  mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
  crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
)
```

Comment: if it is helpful, please marked as answer, thanks!